# Best practice to pass large pipeline option in apache beam

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have a use case where we want in to pass hundred lines of json spec to our apache beam pipeline.? One straight forward way is to create custom pipeline option as mentioned below. Is there any other way where we can pass the input as file?

```
public interface CustomPipelineOptions extends PipelineOptions {
    @Description("The Json spec")
    String getJsonSpec();
    void setJsonSpec(String jsonSpec);
}
```

I want to deploy the pipeline in Google dataflow engine. Even If I pass the spec as filepath and read the file contents inside the beam code before starting the pipeline, how do I bundle the spec file part of pipeline.
P.S Note, I don't want to commit the spec file(in resource folder) part of my source code where my beam code is available. It needs to configurable, i.e I want to pass different spec file for different beam pipeline job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the options as a POJO.

```
public class JsonSpec {
    public String stringArg;
    public int intArg;
}
```

Then reference in your options

```
public interface CustomPipelineOptions extends PipelineOptions {
    @Description("The Json spec")
    JsonSpec getJsonSpec();
    void setJsonSpec(JsonSpec jsonSpec);
}
```

Options will be parsed to the class; [I believe by Jackson though not sure.](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.35.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/options/PipelineOptionsFactory.Builder.html#fromArgs-java.lang.String...-)

I am wondering why you want to pass in "hundreds of lines of JSON" as a pipeline option? This doesn't seem like a very "Beam" way of doing things. Pipeline options should pass configuration; do you really need hundreds of lines of configuration per pipeline run? If you intend to pass data to create a PCollection then better off using TextIO and then processing lines as JSON.

Comment: I want to transform my input PCollection batch using the http api from beam pipeline, so the json spec is required for my pipeline which needs to be a configurable option.

Comment: I have updated my above question.

Comment: I tried this method but it doesn't work. It will throw `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of JsonSpec (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"stringArg": "baz", "intArg": 3}') at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]`

Comment: @OriPopowski Your JSON string is likely not valid. Most likely the quotes are stripped. To escape them properly: `--jsonSpec='{\"stringArg\":\"baz\",\"intArg\":3}'`.

Comment: I'll certainly try this. I posted about it in the mailing list. I'll update how it worked. https://lists.apache.org/thread/tdkzn5czxkzhc2pgnost1ls0cxmjm30t

Comment: @Alec it doesn't work. Without a shadow of a doubt. I tried it from the Dataflow UI and also using API. It will always remove the backslashes. However, it's running locally. So the conclusion here is that this functionality doesn't work on Google Cloud Dataflow.

Answer (score 1):

Beam `PipelineOptions`, as name implies, are intended to be used to provide small configuration parameters to configure a pipeline. `PipelineOptions` are usually read at job submission. So even if you get your json spec to job submission program using a `PipelineOption`, you have to make sure that you write your program so that your `DoFn`s have access to this file at runtime. For this:

1. You have to save your files in a distributed storage system that Dataflow VMs have access to (for example, GCS)
2. You have to pass your input file to the transform that is reading the file.

There are multiple ways to do (2). For example,

- Directly pass in the file path to constructor of your DoFn.
- Pass in the file path as a [side input](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs) to your transform (which allows you to configure it during runtime)